UI Component in Magento 2
         <settings>
             <validation>
                 <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
             </validation>
             <dataType>text</dataType>
             <label translate="true">Field Mapping</label>
         </settings>
         <formElements>
             <select>
                 <settings>
                     <options class="Brady\DataFlow\Model\Config\Source\AttributeSetOptions"/>
                 </settings>
             </select>
         </formElements>
     </field>

I want to have a dependent field named attributes. This should be a drop down field for which values are supposed to be fetched based on the attribute set selected in the above field.
I am not sure How to do write that field in magento 2. Can you help me with that ?
